How to find conditions on parameters, for a system to admit solutions?
I have the following easy equations for positive variables and parameters
    f={-k1 X1 + k2 X2, k1 X1 - k2 X2, -k3 X3 + k4 X4, k3 X3 - k4 X4, 
     k6 X1 X3 - k5 X2 X4, -k6 X1 X3 + k5 X2 X4};
ct = Thread[Variables[f] > 0];eq = Thread[f == 0];
Reduce[Join[ct, eq], var] // FullSimplify

where Reduce finds the right answer, positive solutions are possible only when
k1 == (k2 k4 k6)/(k3 k5)

First question: are there alternatives  to Reduce,  for this type of quantifier elimination,  which might be more efficient? I tried  four other variants which I was hoping might work out, but didn't
Resolve[Exists[var, eq], Reals]
Eliminate[eq, var]
GroebnerBasis[f, tk, var]
SolveAlways[eq, var]

The first answer was a repeat of the question, the second True, and the third {}, and the fourth was wrong, that all k_i=0
Second question: is there a way to force Reduce not to repeat the inequality conditions in its answer?
Now, both questions have been answered already by two users, but I have a minor concern for a new example:
f={a b k13 + b^2 k23 - a^2 k31 - a^2 k32, -a b k12 - a b k13 + b^2 k21 +
   a^2 k31, a b k12 - b^2 k21 - b^2 k23 + a^2 k32};var = {a, b};
ct = Thread[Variables[f] > 0];
Assuming[ct, (Reduce[f == 0, var] // Refine) // FullSimplify]

The answer provided is probably correct, but I would like it in a rational form, without square roots. Is that possible? (I would like to check this with the correct  answer provided on pg. 14 by DA Cox https://faculty.tcu.edu/gfriedman/cbms2018/LectureGuide.pdf
One part, (k23 k31 + k21 (k31 + k32)), does appear in Cox's answer, but the square root renders checking the rest messy)
An even better answer is obtained by
Assuming[ct, (Reduce[f == 0, var] // Refine) // Factor]

Part of the answer
b == (a (k21 k31 + k23 k31 + k21 k32))/(k13 k21 + k12 k23 + k13 k23)

reveals that b/a= K1/K3, but the square roots mess up again the condition on the K, which is as simple as K1 K3=K2^2 (this example is an illustration of the Matrix Tree thm, https://faculty.tcu.edu/gfriedman/cbms2018/Lecture_slides.pdf p.242)

Use Assuming, then the given assumptions are available to all enclosed functions that use the option Assumptions, i.e., Assuming[ct, Reduce[eq, var] // Simplify]

Use Assuming and Refine: Assuming[Thread[Variables[f] > 0], Refine[Reduce[f == 0]]]

is their also a command to make Assumptions global for the session?

@florin $Assumptions = your assumptions

Assuming all variables are positive, as you define ct, you can also use Reduce and Eliminate as follows:
Assuming[ct, Refine[Reduce[Eliminate[eq, {X1, X3}]]]]


k1 == (k2 k4 k6)/(k3 k5)

Note that Eliminate[eq, {X1, X3}] produces:
k1 k3 k5 X2 X4 - k2 k4 k6 X2 X4 == 0

From here, I can use Solve if I want instead of Reduce.
As @user64494 points out, it's a bit confusing because you don't make the distinction between your unknowns and parameters from the beginning.
Also, the following works well:
Assuming[ct, Refine[Reduce[
Eliminate[Assuming[ct, Refine[Reduce[eq]]], {X1, X2, X3, X4}]]]]


k1 == (k2 k4 k6)/(k3 k5)


Your code without Last produces k6 > 0 && k5 > 0 && k4 > 0 && k3 > 0 && k2 > 0 &&   k1 == (k2 k4 k6)/(k3 k5). Also the documentation says "Resolve is in effect automatically applied by Reduce".

You're right, thanks for pointing that out @user64494!

In fact, your Last@Reduce[Exists[{X1, X2, X3, X4}, f == 0 && (And @@ ct)]] is a duplication of my answer in other formulas.

@user64494 I'll delete that part of my answer and leave the one where I use Eliminate first.

It should be noticed that your answer before its first edt included only Last@Reduce[Exists[{X1, X2, X3, X4}, f == 0 && (And @@ ct)]].

@user64494 I mentioned it in a comment and I consider it sufficient. The other thing you mention is already a bad habit that I have observed of you provoking controversy where you participate, and I will not do that, therefore, consider that this is the last response you receive from me.

Sorry, your " where I use Eliminate first" is not clear and may mislead concerning the edits of your answer. Hope I am clear.

The answer above is amazing, since it eliminates all the four variables. However, if I ask for total elimination via Assuming[ct, Refine[Reduce[Eliminate[eq, {X1, X2, X3, X4}]]]]  the answer is just True, so  13.3 fails.  So, we solved one example, but Mathematica cannot solve this way, without help from the user,  the general  problem (known in CRN theory as computing the Wegscheider conditions)

@florin This is a very good observation. In fact, it is also uncomfortable that Reduce repeats the assumptions in its outputs.

But it stops repeating if one uses Asuuming[....

You confused unknowns and parameters, having made use of Variables[f] which outputs {k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6, X1, X2, X3, X4}. The following works well.
f = {-k1 X1 + k2 X2, k1 X1 - k2 X2, -k3 X3 + k4 X4, k3 X3 - k4 X4, 
k6 X1 X3 - k5 X2 X4, -k6 X1 X3 + k5 X2 X4};
Resolve[Exists[{X1, X2, X3, X4}, f == 0], PositiveReals]


-k1 < 0 && -k2 < 0 && -k3 < 0 && -k4 < 0 && -k5 < 0 && -k6 < 0 &&  k1 k3 k5 - k2 k4 k6 == 0

Addition. The code of 14.1
f = {a b k13 + b^2 k23 - a^2 k31 - a^2 k32, -a b k12 - a b k13 + 
b^2 k21 + a^2 k31, a b k12 - b^2 k21 - b^2 k23 + a^2 k32};
Resolve[Exists[{a, b}, f == 0], PositiveReals]


k12 > 0 && k13 > 0 && k21 > 0 && k23 > 0 && k31 > 0 &&  k12^2 + 2 k12 k13 + k13^2 - 4 k21 k31 >= 0 && k32 > 0 &&  k12 k13 k21 k31 + k12^2 k23 k31 + k12 k13 k23 k31 - k21^2 k31^2 -  2 k21 k23 k31^2 - k23^2 k31^2 + k12 k13 k21 k32 + k13^2 k21 k32 +  k12^2 k23 k32 + 2 k12 k13 k23 k32 + k13^2 k23 k32 -  2 k21^2 k31 k32 - 2 k21 k23 k31 k32 - k21^2 k32^2 == 0

answers the additional question by the OP.

It is interesting that that works for you, since on my 13.3 it almost works, producing answer -k1 < 0 && -k2 < 0 && -k3 < 0 && -k4 < 0 && -k5 < 0 && -k6 < 0 && k1 k3 k5 - k2 k4 k6 == 0  A bigger mistery is I had tried the same (my var  was precisely {X1,..,X4}, so I  confused nothing, but I forgot to copy it), but with f==0 replaced by eq={-k1 X1 + k2 X2 == 0, k1 X1 - k2 X2 == 0, -k3 X3 + k4 X4 == 0,
k3 X3 - k4 X4 == 0,
k6 X1 X3 - k5 X2 X4 == 0, -k6 X1 X3 + k5 X2 X4 == 0} and the answer then was True, so in 13.3 it depends on whether you leave ==0  outside, or you thread it! That'sweird

@florin: In 14.1 on Windows eq = {-k1 X1 + k2 X2 == 0, k1 X1 - k2 X2 == 0, -k3 X3 + k4 X4 == 0,    k3 X3 - k4 X4 == 0,    k6 X1 X3 - k5 X2 X4 == 0, -k6 X1 X3 + k5 X2 X4 == 0};Resolve[Exists[{X1, X2, X3, X4}, eq], PositiveReals] results in -k1 < 0 && -k2 < 0 && -k3 < 0 && -k4 < 0 && -k5 < 0 && -k6 < 0 &&   k1 k3 k5 - k2 k4 k6 == 0. You may try it in free WolframCloud.

Up to the documentation, Resolve has been updated in 14.0 (2024).
